# What does S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) mean?

Tags: python-3.x, docstring

I'm learning to use python docstring.

```
>>> print(str.find.__doc__)
S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
...
```

When I print str.find() docstring, I don't understand what this means.

What does S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) mean?

Comment: What do you mean? that is the method signature of the `str.find`method.

Comment: @Jan I want to know what does that mean `[,` in S.find(sub[, start[, end]])

Comment: Have you considered looking in the actual [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)? "*__Optional arguments__ start and end are interpreted as in slice notation*". BTW, the square brackets usually are a way of saying that something is optional.

Comment: The method's signature (and its complete docstring) is shown and explained here for example: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Comment: @Tomerikoo sorry, my apologies. I should have checked the docs. but thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the method [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) in String will take in 3 parameters of which 2 are optional.

Example:

```
 a = "Hello World"
 a.find("World")        # returns 6
 a.find("World", 4)     # returns 6
 a.find("World", 4, 6)  # returns -1 meaning it cannot be found
```

Back to your output:

```
S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
```

- `S` here refers to the String variable which in my case was `a`.
- `-> int` means the function outputs an integer which is by default the position of the found word or `-1` if not found which in my case was `6` and `-1`.
- `sub` refers to the word you are looking for which in my case was `"World"`.
- `start` and `end` refer to the start and end indices as to where to find the string which in my case was `4` and `6` respectively.

Comment: `[, start[, end]]` refers to optional parameters!
I get it now. Thanks so much!